# Mysql workbench 6.3 CE has an issue?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am sometimes in trouble with typing 'select' or 'insert'statement. The error shows me that I type a wrong syntax.  I close the MySQL Workbench program and open it again, the issue sometimes is fixed. But the issue is sometimes still there after reopening the workbench program.

Comment: did you complete the command or did you finished the command with a semicolon `;` ?

Comment: Yes I did. When I compile the whole statement, it shows me "Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax ..."

Comment: Can you add an image of the problem or even the full text of the error in the output window in your question please?